# How to update or access elements in a JQuery Jtable

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

I am new to this plugin and have been struggling with it. The documentation leave a lot to be desired and lacks examples, additionally, there is not much of a support community for it outside of Java. I'm hoping that someone here knows the answer to my question.

I have a dialog that is **outside of the jtable framework** that adds a value to the database. On success, I need to update a select element within the jtable "Add new record" dialog, but cannot see any way of doing this. Short of telling the client to refresh their screen after they've added the value, I'm at a loss.

Is it possible to update the select element, and if so, can someone please either point me to the correct method call within the docs or provide a small example that I can follow? I'm even open to a workaround if someone has one.

---

**EDIT:**

This is a snippet that will attach itself to my select, adding `id="client"` to it. In the dialog that is outside of this framework, when the user adds a value to the database, I need to know how to gain access to this 'client' id element. Since the event did not occur within this snippet, I don't know how to access it. I've tried appending the value using the `client` id but it doesn't work.

```
client: {
    title: 'Name',
    width: '20%',
    input: function (data) {
        if (data.record) {

        }
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post your code otherwise we have nothing definitively to work off of.

Here's some simple examples using jquery and ajax to update an html data table.

```
$.get(
        loadUrl,
        {sid: sid,
         dbitem: dbitem,
         newinfo: newinfo},
        function(responseText){
            $('tbody').append(responseText);//use tbody as selector & append() here
            // or you can use prepend() as your needs
        },
        "html"
    );
```

Here's a fiddle of another example.

http://jsfiddle.net/W4gYY/3/